# webpack 5 error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting './src/style.css')

Tags: javascript, webpack

I started building a project collector using Webpack 5 and I ran into a strange error. When I first run everything works without error, but after updating the styles I get an error even though the new styles are being applied. I found no errors in webpack.conf.js

webpack.config.js:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
const isProd = !isDev;

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        app: './src/index.js',
    },
    output: {
        clean: true,
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        static: './build',
        hot: true,
        port: 9000,
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html'
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                          sourceMap: true,
                        },
                      },
                  ],
            }
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: isProd,
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'async',
            minSize: 20000,
            minRemainingSize: 0,
            minChunks: 1,
            maxAsyncRequests: 30,
            maxInitialRequests: 30,
            enforceSizeThreshold: 50000,
            cacheGroups: {
              defaultVendors: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                priority: -10,
                reuseExistingChunk: true,
              },
              default: {
                minChunks: 2,
                priority: -20,
                reuseExistingChunk: true,
              },
            },
          },
    },
};
```

link to full repository code https://github.com/likeavenus/webpack-build-2021

Comment: Thanks for the repository link!
It helped to reproduce an issue in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an error in my html, I connected the script to the document once again

Answer (score 0):

Just slightly simplify a styles import:

before: *import **css from** "./style.scss";*.
after:  *import "./style.scss";*

```
import "./style.scss";

import some from './some.js';

some();
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
}
```

Comment: I pushed the changes that you suggested, and also deleted the sass just in case, but the problem remained

Comment: With your latest changes not reproducible anymore.  
>>   
main.js:3505 [webpack-dev-server] App updated. Recompiling...  
main.js:3505 [webpack-dev-server] App hot update...  
log.js:24 [HMR] Checking for updates on the server...  
log.js:24 [HMR] Updated modules:  
log.js:24 [HMR]  - ./src/style.css.  
log.js:24 [HMR] App is up to date.  
hotModuleReplacement.js:215 [HMR] Reload all css.

Comment: Weird. When I change styles the error is still reproduced.

Comment: I continued working on the build but still get this error. I will be grateful for help in solving the problem